# How to make generic template to render any queryset passed to it as html table?

Tags: python, django-templates

I need to make a django template that will render any queryset as a table. This means that that I do not know how many columns there will be, nor what the key names are. Thus the template will recevie a context with a queryset called 'data' for instance, from which the template will itterate through the keys to create the column heads, and then itterate through each row, writing out the row values in the correct column. I have the ability to apply any functions to the queryset, such as values(), serialize, etc. when placing it within the context, but I don't have control of the number of columns and their names as that is determined by the query which can be constructed in variable ways. I have no problem getting the keys as a list and itterating through them for the header. My issue is the data rows when I can't specify specific key names. Is there a way to use itterate and next(). I welcome all suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: with 
data = the queryset, and 
data_key = list of the keys

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        {% for data_key in data_keys %}
            <th>{{ data_key }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for row in data %}
         <tr>
            {% for row_item in row.values %}
                <td>{{ row_item }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```